# iOS threads: does this ensure the completion to be called from the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Let’s say I have a function containing some instructions called in another thread, for example the background thread:

```
func myFunc(_ completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    anyActionFromBackgroundThread {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I call this function somewhere:

```
myFunc {
    self.tableView.reloadData() // or any UI action 
}
```

By doing this, am I sure that the UI action, here `tableView.reloadData()`, will be called from the main thread? Or do I need to add a check in the completion?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your function and completion handler seems correct but table will not reload because of not using self. Please use 'self.tableView.reloadData()'

Comment: @amit Yes I forgot about this, I just edited my question. Thanks for this!

Comment: FWIW, a slightly simpler (and more conventional) declaration of your `myFunc` might be as follows `func myFunc(completion: @escaping () -> Void) { ... }`. All of those parentheses don’t improve the legibility and we don’t care about the argument label since we’re using trailing closure syntax...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the anecdote! I'll use this syntax now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in this particular case you know `reloadData` is called from main thread because `myFunc` dispatched the call to the completion closure to the main queue. This is the precise reason why `myFunc` performed the `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

---

By the way, if you ever want to confirm whether something is running on the main queue, you can add a dispatch precondition:

```
myFunc {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))

    self.tableView.reloadData() // or any UI action 
}
```

This makes your code assumptions explicit, and will help you find any incorrect GCD usage during the development process.

Obviously, in this case you're initiating UI updates, and the main thread checker will help identify misuse. You can find this option on Xcode under “Product” » “Scheme” » “Edit Scheme…” » “Run” » “Diagnostics”.

Comment: Thank you for this nice addition!

Answer (score 0):

for below iOS10.0, you can use:

```
func myFunc {

    precondition(Thread.isMainThread)

    self.tableView.reloadData() // or any UI action 
}
```